# Getting an Empty array in props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-table-v7

I am trying to make table using `react-table` in which one of the columns will be a toggle-switch in typescript. I am using the following code to create a `react-switch`.

```
const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns,
        data},(hooks)=> {
            console.log("setting buildings: ",data);
            hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => columns.map((column)=>column.id === "cevacrunningstatus"?{...column,Cell:({row})=>
                {return <BuildingStartStopSwitch row_={row} data__={buildings} setdata={setbuildings}/>}}:column));
        }
    )
```

I am using the following React function component

```
interface props{
    row_:Row.Row<any>;
    data__:BuildingControlStatus[];
    setdata: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<BuildingControlStatus[]>>;
}


const BuildingStartStopSwitch:React.FC<props> = ({row_,data__,setdata}) => {
    const [state,setState] = useState<boolean>(row_.values.runningstatus);
    
    const handleChange = (checked:boolean) => {
        setState(checked);
        console.log("Data before statechange:  ",data__)
        setdata(data__.map((data_)=>row_.values.ccid === data_.ccid?({...data_,runningstatus:checked}):data_))
    }

    console.log("Data after statechange:  ",data__)
    return (
        <Switch onChange={handleChange} checked={state}/>
    );
};

export default BuildingStartStopSwitch;
```

I have the following issue:

1. The array data__ is turning up as an empty array inside `BuildingStartStopSwitch`. The `data` variable which is assigned to `data__` contains items, but the same is not reflected inside `BuildingStartStopSwitch`. I am trying to update the `data` variable(which is the table data) to reflect the status of toggle switch.
2. I have an input cell against each toggle switch in a row. When the switch is checked, the input should be enabled and when the switch is unchecked , it should be disabled. I am not sure how to implement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] your question and copy-paste the `SetStateAction` and its reducer?

Comment: Hi, I am new to react, I am following an example from react-table tutorial on YouTube https://youtu.be/WRKEjPq75BY. I don't have a `setStateAction` in my code as of now. I am trying to modify the ` data` variable so that I can assign the boolean value to `isDisabled` variable of react select. I would be grateful if you could point to some examples

Comment: Oh sorry, it's the `BuildingControlStatus` that I'd like to check

Comment: ```export interface BuildingControlStatus{
    ccid:string|number;
    name:string;
    buildingmode:string;
    controlsystemstatus:string;
    runningstatus:boolean;
    buildinginterface:string;
    buildinginterfacestatus:string;
    buildingoperation:string;
}```

Comment: All the code looks OK to me. The problem should be somewhere else. Can you post the `setdata` function that is passed to `<BuildingStartStopSwitch setdata={xxx}/>`

Comment: `setbuildings` is set as `setdata`. `setbuildings` is an attribute from the output of `useState`.  `const [buildings,setbuildings] = useState<BuildingControlStatus[]>([])`

Comment: @lepsch Hi any idea what's wrong?

Comment: No... the code looks fine to me. Something is wrong somewhere else. Would you please [edit] your question and copy-paste the entire code if possible? Try to strip it down a bit just to have a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)